# How do pointer to local structures get translated to webassembly?

Tags: c++, webassembly

Unfortunately I'm unable to get a working toolchain to compile C/C++ down to a wasm file, but I was hoping a kind soul could help me out here. Given the program fragment:

```
struct foo {
    int a;
    float b;
};

void function(foo * p);

void my_program() {
    struct foo my_foo;
    my_foo.a = 1;
    my_foo.b = -3.0F;
    foo(&my_foo);
}
```

what does the wasm code for `my_program` look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to assume you mean what does the wast textual format look like?

I adjusted up a couple things in your code so that it would compile:

```
struct foo {
    int a;
    float b;
};

extern void bar(struct foo * p);

void my_program() {
    struct foo my_foo;
    my_foo.a = 1;
    my_foo.b = -3.0F;
    bar(&my_foo);
}
```

Compiling it using emscripten/binaryen and then using wasm2wast:

```
emcc -s WASM=1 -s SIDE_MODULE=1 -O2 str.c -o str.js
wasm-dis str.wasm -o str.wast
```

Note that without `-s SIDE_MODULE=1 -O2`, emscripten pulls in a bunch of the standard library (malloc, etc) and the wast file is 10,000 lines long. I'm assuming you probably just want the fairly simple wasm/wast result without all the linkages/inclusions.

That results in the following wast file:

```
(module
 (type $0 (func (param i32)))
 (type $1 (func))
 (import "env" "memoryBase" (global $import$0 i32))
 (import "env" "_bar" (func $import$1 (param i32)))
 (import "env" "memory" (memory $0 256))
 (import "env" "table" (table 0 anyfunc))
 (import "env" "tableBase" (global $import$4 i32))
 (global $global$0 (mut i32) (i32.const 0))
 (global $global$1 (mut i32) (i32.const 0))
 (export "_my_program" (func $0))
 (export "__post_instantiate" (func $2))
 (export "runPostSets" (func $1))
 (func $0 (type $1)
  (local $var$0 i32)
  (local $var$1 i32)
  (block $label$0
   (set_local $var$0
    (get_global $global$0)
   )
   (set_global $global$0
    (i32.add
     (get_global $global$0)
     (i32.const 16)
    )
   )
   (i32.store
    (tee_local $var$1
     (get_local $var$0)
    )
    (i32.const 1)
   )
   (f32.store offset=4
    (get_local $var$1)
    (f32.const -3)
   )
   (call $import$1
    (get_local $var$1)
   )
   (set_global $global$0
    (get_local $var$0)
   )
  )
 )
 (func $1 (type $1)
  (nop)
 )
 (func $2 (type $1)
  (block $label$0
   (set_global $global$0
    (get_global $import$0)
   )
   (set_global $global$1
    (i32.add
     (get_global $global$0)
     (i32.const 5242880)
    )
   )
   (call $1)
  )
 )
 ;; custom section "dylink", size 5
)
```

Note that `memoryBase`, `tableBase`, `__post_instantiate`, and `runPostSets`are emscripten additions for platform memory integration/initialization. `memoryBase` is basically the start of the C stack and the value is copied by `__post_instantiate` into `$global$0` (which is global to all functions in this module). When `my_program` is called the first thing that happens is we adjust the stack pointer by 16 to point to where the compiler has "allocated" space for my_foo structure on stack. We now do a couple of `i32.store` operations using `offset=X` to update the fields within `foo`. When the function returns we restore the stack pointer (`$global$0`) to where it was when we entered the function.

Comment: What I'm trying to understand is how local storage is allocated to provide space for the struct. It seems that global 2 is acting like some sort of explicit stack pointer; it's copied into local 0, incremented by 16 (`sizeof foo`) and on procedure exit, it's reset back to the value in local 0. Would it be correct to assume that the environment provides the "stack pointer" as a global pointer?

Comment: @JohnKällén Yes, that's my understanding. I updated the wast using wasm-dis from binaryen since it has more intelligent disassembly and more annotations. I also added some explanatory text for the code explaining that.